# highlight the search text in prime-ng autocomplete

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, primeng

I am using the PrimeNG AutoComplete with angular 7.
                             In the auto complete I return a list of all the 
                          items that their 
                            description contains the search text.
              I would like to highlight matched words in each element of the shown list.

```
     <p-autoComplete 
                    #autoComplete 
                     (onFocus)="autoComplete.handleDropdownClick()"
                    [suggestions]="results"
                    (completeMethod)="search($event)"
                    [multiple]="true"
                    field="Path"
                    (onSelect)="selectedValues($event)"
                    (onUnselect)="unSelectedValues($event)"
                    placeholder="Select Domain"
                    emptyMessage= {{noResult}}
                    [formControl]="dataModelControl"
                    >
              <ng-template let-value pTemplate="item">
               <div class="ui-helper-clearfix">
               <span [innerHTML]="value.Path | highlight : 
               toHighlight"></span
               </div>  
               </ng-template>
           </p-autoComplete>
```

This is the definition of the `highlight` pipe:

```
@Pipe({ name: 'highlight ' })
export class HighlightPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(text: string, search): string {  
          const pattern = search
          .replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&")
          .split(' ')
            .filter(t => t.length > 0)
           .join('|');
           const regex = new RegExp(pattern, 'gi');

            return search ? text.replace(regex, match => `<b>${match}</b>`) : 
                 text;
              }
             }
            }  
            //in ts file
            search(event) {

      if (event.query) {
        this.toHighlight = event.query;
         this.results = this.data.filter(option => {
          return option.Path.toLowerCase().indexOf(event.query.toLowerCase()) 
         >= 0
         });
          } else {
             this.results = this.data.slice();
            }
           }
```

Comment: this code works fine. i made a mistake in specifying a name to the pipe. @Pipe({'highlight'})- i gave a space after highlight. so it was giving me a error.